# extract variable from json style output in Linux command

Tags: json, linux, awk, grep

I try to use the AWS secrets manager in the linux system. I could use aws cli command

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id abc_account --version-stage AWSCURRENT
```

to get following output

```
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:abc_account-XhteiW",
    "Name": "abc_account",
    "VersionId": "89637ef4-4594-4c63-9887-3f7d2c7ccc6f",
    "SecretString": "{\"username\":\"abc_account\",\"password\":\"PASSWORD111\"}",
    "VersionStages": [
        "AWSCURRENT"
    ],
    "CreatedDate": "2021-02-08T23:57:58.325000-05:00"
}
```

what I need is to save the password PASSWORD111 into a variable var1 in the linux. something like

```
var1=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id svc_vma_insights_data_platform --version-stage AWSCURRENT | awk XXXXXX )
or 
var1=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id svc_vma_insights_data_platform --version-stage AWSCURRENT | grep XXXXXX )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is extracting the secret string from the JSON output, and then extracting the password from *that* JSON:

```sh
passwd=$(aws ...  | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r '.password')
```

Answer (score 1):

On linux you may try this `gnu grep`:

```
var1=$(aws ... | grep -oP 'password\W+\K[^"\\]+')
echo "$var1"

PASSWORD111
```

**Command regex:**

- `password\W+`: Match text `password` followed by 1+ non-word characters
- `\K`: Reset match info
- `[^"\\]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not a `"` and not a `\`

Comment: Great. That works fine. Thank you so much.